# automate addition of certain text and tables across multiple shared google word documents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I was wondering if there is some kind of flow/language to automate to add additional text and tables across multiple google documents (word specifically).

thanks
Gordon

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation. And, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, for example, how about using Google Apps Script for your situation? I thought that Google Apps Script is used, your goal might be achieved. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

*Since you want to automate a task in Google Docs, your best bet would be to use Google Apps Script.*

Apps Script is a powerful scripting platform developed by Google for developing light-weight application within Google Workspace.

As for what you want to achieve, the `DocumentApp` would be the most useful for this. As for the methods to use, the following ones can be of help to you:

- `openById(id)` - which will return the Google Document with the specified id;
- `getBody()` - which will return the body of the document;
- `appendParagraph(text) - which will create and append a new paragraph containing the specified text contents;
- `appendTable(cells)` - which adds a new table containing a `TableCell` for each specified string value.

As for automating this task, you can always create a time-based trigger which will run at the time you specify.

#### Reference

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview);
- [DocumentApp Class - openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openbyidid);
- [Document Class - getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getbody);
- [Body Class - appendParagraph(text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendparagraphtext);
- [Body Class - appendTable(cells)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendtablecells);
- [Time-driven Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).